# How's 'Is Tom Brady a cheater?' a 'straw-man expression...'?

Tags: fallacies

[Source, penultimate para:](http://www.newyorker.com/news/sporting-scene/humiliation-tom-brady?intcid=mod-most-popular)  'The Humiliation of Tom Brady', by Ian Crouch, 2015 Jan 23

> ♦ “This has raised a lot of uncomfortable conversations from people around this country who view you, a three-time Super Bowl champion and a two-time M.V.P., as their idol,” someone said. “The question they’re asking themselves is, ‘What’s up with our hero?’ So can you answer right now: Is Tom Brady a cheater?” ♦ This isn’t the kind of question that expects an answer; **it’s a timeless straw-man expression of fan populism—”Say it ain’t so, Joe.”** Another reporter was more to the point: “A lot of fans are disappointed in the situation. For those, is this a moment where you should pause and say, whether it was by design or accidental, is this a moment to just say, ‘I’m sorry to the fans of the NFL and to the fans of Tom Brady’?” Again, no one watching had the slightest idea yet what Brady needed to be sorry for—you can’t hurry along the Oprah moment.

I know little of philosophy and nothing of football, but does the bold allege the preceding question (that I surrounded with lozenges: ♦) as a Strawman Fallacy (the basics of which I read)? How? This scandal concerns Brady; so Brady is a subject. What's the straw man?

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't seem to me that this is being used correctly in the logical sense of *a weak argument introduced for the purposes of seeming to strengthen the position of an argument supporting the opposite position.*

In context it seems more like they mean *straw man* as representing a invented version of what the "fan on the street" is supposed to be thinking.  The example "Say it ain't so, Joe," is a reference to a famous, but probably invented story of a little boy pleading with Shoeless Joe Jackson to deny charges of having thrown the World Series.

It's related to the logical meaning --in both cases, a statement is introduced as supposedly representing a point of view that it does not accurately represent --however, it doesn't have the same functionality *vis a vis* a line of argument.

Comment: Thank you. The reporters want 'the fan on the street' to demand Brady to '”Say it ain’t so, Joe.” Right? So why's this a `spurious example`? If I'm right, then is **straw man** used correctly?

Comment: Will you please to respond in your answer, and not as a comment?